# ko.utils.arrayFirst always returns null when not handling else block with non-empty string

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

This works correctly:

```
  self.getById = function(id) {
        return ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.PostArray(), function(item) {
            if (item.postId === id) {
                return item;
            }
            else {
                return 'not found';
            }
        });
    };

    console.log(self.PostArray().length);
    console.log(self.getById(170));
```

But if I put `return ''` or `return null` in else block I always get null, why is that?

Comment: Knockout provides `ko.utils.arrayFirst` that will execute a function against each item in our array and returns the first item where the function evaluates to true. otherwise it returns null

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're not using `arrayFirst` correctly. `arrayFirst` expects a function that returns `true` or `false`, evaluating each item. The first item for which the function returns `true` is returned. Here's how it should look:

```
self.getById = function(id) {
    return ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.PostArray(), function(item) {
        return item.postId === id;
    }) || 'not found';
};
```

Basically return `'not found'` if `item` is falsey (`null` in this case most likely).

See [this article](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html) for more information on the various utility functions in KnockoutJS.

Comment: That is the only version that in some case returned something, but I couldn't get it work like this.. I have item with PostId=170 when looking through firebug, but it always returns null.. With your example 'not found' even though it exists..

Comment: Actually, it works, key was in my last comment `PostId != postID`, but I'm still curious why my first example worked.

Comment: probably because `null` and `''` are both falsey values, while `not found` is "truthy". This is most likely equivalent to returning `false` from Knockout's perspective

Comment: Yep, that's probably it, it would always return first item, and this was first item on in array. Thanks!