# KnockoutJS ArrayFirst doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, observable

I have already tried the solutions here:

- This: [knockout arrayfirst not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41600623/knockout-arrayfirst-not-working-as-expected)
- This: [ko.utils.arrayFirst always returns null when not handling else block with non-empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21222480/ko-utils-arrayfirst-always-returns-null-when-not-handling-else-block-with-non-em)
- This: [Knockout Check If Existing in observableArray before Push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29957343/knockout-check-if-existing-in-observablearray-before-push)

But nothing works for me. I am checking if an item is already existing in the observable array

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Summary(), function (item) {

            var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.filteredSummary(), function (a) {
                return a.Sku == item.Sku()
            });

            if (!match) {
                // Do push
            }
        });
```

Am I doing something wrong? This always returns null even though when debugged, it founded a match.

I attached the snippet of the values:
[image]

Comment: Run your project, put a debugger inside arrayFirst and console log for us:
"item" and "a" and update your post with a snipet

Comment: Hi @MKougiouris updated

Comment: why a ``a.Sku`` is observable ?  ``==`` with a ``item.Sku()`` - value ?? observable vs value ?? is this wrong ?

Comment: be carefull when debugging. You are logging different things than what you are comparing down below, giving you false info. You are logging the result of ko.toJSON that would actually hide from you whether or not the property that was passed was an observable or not, since it will return the unwrapped value. In your example if "a.Sku" was an observable you would correctly read x === y, but that would not mean that a.Sku === item.Sku(). "a.Sku" would be a function, while "item.Sku()" would be an actual string! just leaving this here as a future help note

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the statement,

`return item.Sku() === a.Sku()`

=== : equal value and equal type, 
==  : equal to,

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp

In your case both the value and the type of the two summary objects must be equal.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try this one

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Summary(), function (item) {

            var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.filteredSummary(), function (a) {
                return a.Sku() == item.Sku();
            });

            if (!match) {
                // Do push
            }
        });
```

If this workd, the problem was that a.SKu was an observable and you were not evaluating it! Read my comment on your original question